# How is "être à une ou deux pièces de pain près" interpreted?

Tags: expressions

In conversation, I said jokingly:

> Bon, ça craint. Pourquoi tout le monde est si radin dans le coin, hein ?
>   C’est pas comme si elles étaient **à une ou deux pièces de pain près**! Ou 5... ou 10.

The thing is that this phrasing was not immediately and properly understood by a French speaker I was talking with. Which leads me to wonder if I've got its meaning straight?

What I wanted to say was: Why are they so reluctant to share their food while they could easily afford a few pieces of bread?! -- they have plenty of bread, so it shouldn't be that big of a deal for them to be a few pieces of bread short.

Answer (score 4):

*Pièce de pain* is not idiomatic. It kind of sounds like a coin that can only be used to buy bread or something.

"*A piece of bread*" in French is "*un bout de pain*".

Also it's kind of weird to count up to 5 or 10 *bouts de pain*, but it depends on what those pieces of bread were.

Comment: Hi. Just to be sure... By "une ou deux pièces de pain", I referred to a few different kinds of bread, such as a croissant, a quiche, a sandwich... rather than a few pieces of a loaf of bread for which I'd then use "quelques bouts de pain". Does it still sound odd?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Even worse! Quiches and croissants are **not** bread! And I wouldn't call a sandwich a piece of bread either.

Comment: Interesting, as at least here in Japan all of them fall under the 'bread' category. Goes to show how French people take bread seriously!

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens  I wouldn't make too much of that; it's not different from the point of view of the English, who make a difference between plain bread and bread products. Such a difference is made in [French]( https://atmosphereprotectrice.fr/applications/modified-atmosphere-packaging-bread-products) with the term "produit de panification";  another difference, quite natural, is made between "boulangerie" and viennoiserie" (catégorie in which you find croissants, chocolatines, pain au lait, etc.). The English fail apparently to discriminate between pastry and "viénnoiserie".

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Also Idk why I didn't mention it earlier but you can't say "*un bout de pain*" for something whole; It has to be pieces of a loaf. Can be a slice of bread, or a piece you've taken out of a slice. If it's a whole thing, just say "*un pain*" (even if it's really small)

Answer (score 1):

I'm French and I understand it the way you mean it. I think most French people will immediately understand this expression. It is creatively close to some expressions we employ but still it is not a French expression. The French speaker you talked to did not make lots of efforts to understand you though :)

Answer (score -3):

**I**

« Ça craint » n'est pas du français standard, c'est quelque chose comme du parler « branché ». Voici ce qu'en dit [l'internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/ca-craint/).

> Sens : C'est nul, c'est dangereux. Origine : Selon le contexte, cette expression peut prendre un sens différent, mais elle sert toujours à exprimer un rejet ou une opinion négative. Apparue dans les années 80, la locution « ça craint » était employée majoritairement par les adolescents. Elle est moins en vogue aujourd'hui.

Vous avez aussi la variante plus prononcée « [ça craint du boudin](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A7a_craint_du_boudin) » qui n'est évidemment pas de la langue sérieuse, une véritable horreur dans la bouche d'un locuteur qui se respecte.

Donc, pour commencer un francophone, qui n'a pas à assimiler l'argot de la langue ni le parler des « teenyboppers » et autres sections extravagantes de la population, ne connait pas forcémment cela (il est d'ailleurs fortement conseillé d'éliminer un tel vocabulaire se son langage).

**II**

L'expression « à **X** près » où **X** peut être quasiment n'importe quoi, selon le contexte, ne constitue pas un problème ; vous pouvez dire toutes sortes de choses ;

- pas à **un bout de pain** près
- pas à **quelques morceaux de pain** près
- pas à **un ou deux morceaux de pain** près
- pas à **quarante miches de pain** près (distribution de grande surface)
- pas à **cinq ou six morceaux de pain** près
- pas à **un morceau de pain** près, **ou même cinq, ou dix**
- pas à **deux ou trois morceaux de pain** près, **ou dix ou vingt**

Ce que l'on ne peut pas faire naturellement c'est, dans une expression d'approximation avec « ou », utiliser un écart plus grand que un. Si on veut surenchérir sur une première approximation on peut le faire comme dans les deux dernier exemples ci-dessus, c'est à dire pas en tant que partie de l'approximation de base (trop long).

Le sens est simplement que X en plus ou X en moins n'ont aucune espèce d'importance dans la situation considérée.

Ce qui ajoute à la difficulté dans « **I** » pour le locuteur familier avec la langue standard c'est le terme non idiomatique pour « morceau » ; on emploie « pièce » pour la viande et pas pour les petits morceaux comme par exemple un steak (une épaule de mouton, un gigot, etc.) ; on l'emploie aussi pour la pâtisserie, mais encore une fois, seulement pour une confection importante et d'ailleurs seulement dans le terme « pièce montée », (ce qui est un énorme gâteaux que les gens commandent surtout pour les mariages).

Comment: L'argot fait partie de la langue, que tu le veuilles ou non. Pourquoi émettre un jugement dessus ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat L'argot a toujours été la langue des bas-fonds, la langue de ceux qui déconnectés de la société et de sa littérature construisent un second langage parce qu'ils n'ont ni affinité pour la langue standard ni connaissance de celle-ci. Il n'y a que dernièrement que l'on a commencé à vouloir rendre l'argot une partie légitime du langage. L'argot c'est essentiellement une langue en double et une langue trés vulgaire ; je ne partagerai jamais les idées qui font qu'il entre en vogue ; « Argotez, argotez…" n'est pas un livre pour moi, ni toujours pour un bon nombre de français.

Comment: Je ne vais pas en débattre ici mais je ne suis absolument pas d'accord avec cet avis, c'est même l'inverse, l'argot est une richesse de la langue.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat C'est bien ce qu'un certain courant d'esprit apparemment dominant laisse entendre, ça serait l'inverse, mais pas selon mon point de vue et je crois que le  point de vue opposé au mien est arbitraire, essentiellement celui de ceux qui ont été élevés dans la culture de l'argot ; leurs fortes habitudes mènent leur façon de penser et ils ne sont capable d'aucun raisonnement, il refusent même la discussion et se rabattent sur des sentiments, des intuitions, en somme beaucoup de tergiversation.